# How to combine quickly and my python program?

Tags: application-development, python, quickly, programming

Firstly, I'm not sure if I'm allowed to ask this question. I'll delete it if it's not welcome. I'm after some guidance on how to start programming.

Perhaps I need to start somewhere else, but I'm interested in learning to code, however I've not taken a single course in computer science in my life. I've read tutorials but I prefer to start writing programs and ask how to do things when I get stuck. I've written a program in python today and it works very well, and I've written a few things in python now, but only simple programs like the one I wrote today http://paste.ubuntu.com/1147685/ which I managed to do without help, (only following some things on the python website) but what I really want is to write a GUI program. I've heard "quickly" is a good program and I've installed that and I can now use glade to make simple windows with buttons and text boxes, but that's about as far as I've got. It seems to me that all the tutorials I've read on quickly and, is it GTK? or GTK+? or pyGTK? I'm not sure, but one of them anyway makes the kind of things I'm after. A program which runs on python and has clickable buttons and doesn't need an open terminal. Right so the question:

Could someone please tell me which tutorial I need to read to allow me to make a program written in python using quickly (the bit where you type quickly edit - I have no idea what to put in those files!)

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For learning Python, there's a few sites you should go:

## http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/

http://www.korokithakis.net/tutorials/python/

Interactive tutorial

http://www.learnpython.org/

Ubuntu related stuff

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Programming/Python

http://www.trainsignal.com/blog/introduction-to-python-programming-in-ubuntu-linux

## Programing in Quickly

http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tools/quickly/

Not sure about quickly but there's a GUI tool that many people use on Ubuntu to code in Python -  IDLE

http://onecore.net/how-topython-programming-under-ubuntu.htm

It's not the GUI tool itself that you must be concerned, but learning the basics itself.

Comment: Thank you, that's a very detailed answer. I shall take the time to read those tutorials.